# Binding ComboBox SelectedItem to double

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, combobox, double

My ComboBox's `ItemsSource` is binding to a `List<double> options` and the `SelectedItem` is binding to a property `double SelectedOption`.

If `options` contains the values `0.0060F, 0.0075F, 0.0100F` and `SelectedItem = 0.0060F`, the ComboBox does should, but does not, reflect this. Instead, selecting the ComboBox shows the `options` list items with their strange decimal representations. Is it even possible to do data binding on variables of type `double` with their unpredictable representation?

**Code**

ViewModel:

```
//Properties
public List<double> Options{get;set;}
public double SelectedOption{get;set;}

//Constructor
public ViewModel()
{
    Options =  new List<double>();
    Options.Add(0.0060F);
    Options.Add(0.0075F);
    Options.Add(0.0100F);

    SelectedOption = 0.0060F;
}
```

Binding:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOption, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The options that are shown in the ComboBox are:

- 0.00600000005215406
- 0.00749999983236194
- 0.00999999977648258

Comment: Provide some code. This should work w/o problems.

Comment: Are you saying Double.ToString() is giving you varying formats, depending on the value. Or that the inherent inaccuracy of floating points isn't giving you the exact value you added?

Comment: I've added code of how I am setting everything up. When the application is debugging, all of these floats show up in Visual Studio watches with the exact value they are assigned. Even using .ToString() in a watch would show the value I assigned and not the long decimal numbers found in the list in the post.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I believe it is arising from the inaccuracy of the floating points. But it seems that 0.0060F == 0.0060F would be true though, and that the binding would work based on that. The list contains a 0.0060F and the selected option is set to 0.0060F, seems like those would correlate.

Comment: Start by dropping those `F` suffixes. F is for Float, D (default) is for double.

Comment: And it will be much more accurate to track SelctedIndex instead of SelectedItem.

Comment: I'm afraid not, basically if it's important to be right at your chosen precision use a fixed point type (e.g. decimal) not a floating point. FP doesn't mean accurate or precise it means there's a decimal point floating about somewhere in there. By the time you've added the overhead for dealing with FP inaccuracies, any so called speed advantage will be long gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should give a read at what floating points are: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx

Those values are used to give a as close as possible to reality representation of numbers. If you want exact values, use System.Decimal

Comment: Thank you for this reference. I had the understanding that if two doubles were assigned the same value that they would be equal, but that is not so. I had heard about Decimal, but it is slower. Looks like it might be my only option though. Thanks again!

Comment: Just checking back in, Decimal does solve this just fine. Not really at a point in development of this app yet to see if it causes slow downs, but I can't see it being too bad.

Comment: As it is said in the article, floating values are perfect to calculate natural numbers, like temperatures, lengths, colors... In video games the need to calculate numbers as fast as possible is critical, and that's why a little loss of precision can bring a lot of performance (see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root))

Comment: The issues with floating points do not apply here, it's perfectly possible to fill an ItemsControl with `double`s.

Comment: Of course you can put doubles and format it, but don't expect to have a precise value. Floats are faster than Decimals doesn't mean that Decimals are not fast.